# Pass className as other prop than styleName

Tags: reactjs, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

How do I pass a CSS module class name as a different prop than `styleName`?

```
import './MyStyles.css'

<ThirdPartyComponent
  styleName='this-works'
  activeClassName='i want to pass my css module classes here' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import styles from './MyStyles.css'

<ThirdPartyComponent
    className={styles['this-works']}
    activeClassName={styles['my-css-module-class-name']}
/>
```